# Black screen with backlight at startup

Tags: grub, hp

I am using the newest version of Elementary OS (as of 24 Sep 2023)
using a HP 250 G5 and whenever i turn on my linux computer, it just shows a black screen with backlight, but no black line or anything.
It was working not too long ago, i finished the installation of Elementary OS after attempting to use another OS (PearOS, which failed) and it told me to remove the USB, then nothing happened. I turned off pc and turned on again and the GRUB menu appears, i open Elementary OS and black screen. Now, not even GRUB appears, just black screen with backlight ON.

Answer (score 0):

### found problem

The GPU / Graphics Card failed and no longer works when connected to external monitor orr built in screen.

-

This may be helpful with anyone with the same issue this may be the issue.
You know the OS is running and the screen but there’s no output? Dead GPU.